# Apiman 2.0.0 security vulnerabilities

Tags: security, keycloak, apiman

We have passed Apiman-2.0.0.final through security scans and came up with some critical/high vulnerabilities, mostly relevant to keycloak-core-10.0.2.
Fixes for this vulnerability are available in higher versions of keycloak.

I would like to know how do you handle these scenarios.
Should we repackage the war locally for us to use? We can create a pull request if it works.
Should we open a Jira item? I cannot see 2.0.0 being supported on red hat  Jira. https://issues.redhat.com/projects/APIMAN/summary

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great community platform for finding answers, however, it is not always the correct choice: In your case there is certainly a github project community with Issues and Pull Requests to discuss and handle exactly such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post issues on our GitHub issue tracker, not stack overflow https://github.com/apiman/apiman/issues

We're using a newer version of Keycloak for the upcoming community release. You can indeed use your own separate Keycloak instance (recommended for a real deployment), rather than the one bundled in the quickstart.

Comment: BTW, to anyone reading this thread, please consider upgrading to the newest version of Apiman rather than sticking to 2.0.0.Final - many versions have been released since.